# Разница между FOREIGN KEY и FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-key

В [MySQL документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) написано следующее:

> MySQL supports foreign keys, which let you cross-reference related data across tables, and foreign key constraints, which help keep this spread-out data consistent.

Вопрос:
В чем разница между foreign key constraints и foreign keys в этом предложении?

*(из "let you cross-reference related data across tables" и "which help keep this spread-out data consistent" разница мне не понятна)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
( 
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  value VARCHAR(50),
  idKek INT,
  CONSTRAINT fk_idKek FOREIGN KEY(idKek) references MtSecondTable(idKek)
)

CREATE TABLE MyTable
( 
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  value VARCHAR(50),
  idKek INT,
  FOREIGN KEY(idKek) references MtSecondTable(idKek)
)
```

В первом случае вы сами задаёте название для CONSTRAINT, во втором оно сгенерируется автоматически. Вот и вся разница.